# Does Firefox extension update on users' machines by the time the author uploads a new version?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, auto-update

Does a Firefox extension update on users' machines at the time the author uploads a new version or does the extension need to pass the full/preliminary review first? If it needs to pass a review first, then will it automatically update to the new version on users' computers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're talking about `addons.mozilla.org`...

You need to pass a review first!

- Add-ons on the prelim. track need to pass another prelim. review (or upgrade to full review status)
- Add-ons on the full review track need to pass another full review. A prelim. review will not enable updates to the version.

Please see: [After the review](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/policies/reviews#full-after)

PS: SO isn't really the place to ask questions like this. The [developer forums](https://forums.mozilla.org/addons/), amo-editors mailing list, or IRC are more appropriate.

Comment: I have asked and received no reply yet! So, that's what I guessed too. But, are you sure that a prelim. review will not enable updates to the version? According to their [site](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/policies/reviews#preliminary-after) it will.

Comment: I'm actually a volunteer reviewer for AMO ;) If you're on the full track you need to pass full review. The section you linked is about the prelim. track.

Comment: I am currently on the preliminary. It has not been reviewed yet at all! But users have installed it and I have uploaded a new version (with minor changes). So, I guess after being reviewed the new version will take place on users' machines? I also guess for future updates, will it need to pass again from the preliminary review? And if I decide to move on full review later, updates will still take place right? Thank you :)

Comment: Oh, now I see. If my extension was already on full review  it would need to pass a full one again in order for the updates to take effect (So basically you can't downgrade on prelim. review?). However, as I said before my extension has not been reviewed yet at all, but people have installed it and need to pass an update. I am currently waiting for a prelim. review.